# Mark tasks in org-mode to show up in agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is there a way to mark tasks in org-mode (similar to how you can mark files in Dired) so that they will show up on an Agenda view or in a sparse tree?

I'm familiar with using TODO keywords. But I was hoping to find something quick and temporary... like a "quick select" mode.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to decide which utility will be used to generate the agenda view (there are three to choose from) and consider setting up `org-agenda-custom-commands` to make repeat custom searches easily accessible.  You should also read about sparse trees in the org-manual.  In addition to the sparse trees (e.g., `org-occur`), there are `org-tags-view`, `org-search-view`, and `org-agenda-list`.  Here is the link to sparse-tree documentation:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-trees.html  Here is the link to custom commands:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html

Comment: Be sure to also read the advanced searching section of the org-mode manual:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  Here is a link to the manual regarding agenda views:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html

Comment: Thanks! I have created some basic Agenda views using `org-agenda-custom-commands` which relied on tags and todo keywords. But I was curious about is whether there is some additional way to flag (or 'mark') Todos, similar to the way that you can temporarily mark files in Dired mode? I mention this because I really like the idea of manually building up a Today list by quickly flagging Todos from my Projects outlines, but without permanently altering their Todo keywords or tags...

Comment: I would recommend just using priorities --- `[#A]`, `[#B]`, `[#C]`, `[#D]`, and `[#E]`, and/or just nothing for the priority.  You can use shift-up/down to change them easily.  The search criteria can be based on priorities, and organized either up or down.  `(setq org-highest-priority ?A) (setq org-lowest-priority ?E) (setq org-default-priority ?A)`  The task looks like this:  `* Next Action [#B] This is the title. :tag:`